# Compiling error when calling a function pointer in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am writing a program that calls a function pointer that points to a function from another file. When I compiled the program, I received an error message from the compiler saying that there was an expected expression. 
Here is one of the four errors produced:

```
error: expected expression
(*get_num)(int *, int *);
```

The compiler says that the expression is expected between the `(` and the `int`.
The same error is shown for each of the other three function pointer calls. 
Am I calling the the function pointer correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getnum(int items[], int *amount);
int sortnum(int items[], int amount);
int printnum(int items[], int amount);
int searchnum(int items[], int amount);

int (*get_num)(int *, int *);
int (*sort_num)(int *, int);
int (*print_num)(int *, int);
int (*search_num)(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int items[maxitem];
    int amount;

    get_num = getnum;
    sort_num = sortnum;
    print_num = printnum;
    search_num = searchnum;

    (*get_num)(int *, int *);
    (*sort_num)(int, int);
    (*print_num)(int, int);
    (*search_num)(int, int);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a function, you need to provide suitable values as arguments. The call

```
(*get_num)(int *, int *);
```

doen't do that.

Use

```
(*get_num)(items, &amount);
```

or the more readable:

```
get_num(items, &amount);
```

Make similar changes for the other calls.

```
(*sort_num)(items, amount);
(*print_num)(items, amount);
(*search_num)(items, amount);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me get rid of the error messages. However, now when I compile the program, the compiler gives me this message: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: @JWu, have you defined the functions `getnum`, `printnum`, `sortnum`, and `searchnum`?